# How can I use Gulp to embed the contents of a css file that is imported into an html file with @import?

Tags: html, css, gulp

I'm in a pickle and could really use some help. I'm attempting to add a task to my gulpfile that would embed a linked stylesheet within an HTML file.  I know that there are several gulp plugins that will embed linked stylesheets, but they only handle linked styles that use the  tag.

I'm building out responsive HTML email templates with MJML (templating language) and rendering out the final HTML with the gulp-mjml plugin. The problem is that MJML won't allow me to use  tags and only seems to allow @import.

Is there a solution similar to gulp-smooshie that would achieve the same result, but using @import?